# Jump to another line of code in mixed PHP/HTML document

Tags: php

I would like to ask probably simple question. Consider following php page:

```
<p>Name of my town is:</p>
<?php echo "London"; 
//if ($condition=="dad_display") then display dad'town, else display mum's town. 
?>

<p>Name of dad's town is:</p>
<?php echo "Prague"; ?>

<p>Name of mum's town is:</p>
<?php echo "Berlin"; ?>
```

is there any way how to circumvent HTML/PHP code inbetween desired beginning and target line of code? (I can not use goto statement...) and I DO NOT want to echo every single HTML line manually (cause in my real page there is a bunch of html code). Otherwise it would be easy.

Thanks very much for reply.

Comment: why not?   
just use PHP regular way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the [alternative syntax](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) of PHP conditional would be best; it's designed to be mixed into the page code.

```
<p>Name of my town is:</p>
<?php echo "London"; ?>

<?php if ($condition=="dad_display"): ?> 

<p>Name of dad's town is:</p>
<?php echo "Prague"; ?>

<?php else: ?>

<p>Name of mum's town is:</p>
<?php echo "Berlin"; ?>

<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: I doubt it was intentionally designed for that. Most likely it was considered later. And it should be mentioned that regular syntax would work as well

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel: Why would it not have been designed for that? PHP is a templating language, so it would seem that is the most likely reason for the alternative syntax.